# Python iterate to remove newlines takes too long. Can my code be optimized better?

Tags: python, file-io, jython

I have a few lines of Python code that reads a file (1 column x 900 rows), then creates a JSON object from the list. The problem that I am running into is when trying to remove the newlines from each item in the list. Here are a few examples:

This code takes approximately 11 seconds to read (900 lines):

```
fh = open(wholefName)
fc = fh.read()
fh.close()
```

This code takes approximately 17 minutes:

```
fh = open(wholefName)
fc = fh.read()
fh.close()
markerArray = fc.splitlines()
```

If, instead, I use "fc = fh.readlines", then each item in the list has an "\n" at the end. I have also tried placing .split() in the json_list def at: "lst.append(pn.split())".

This is what my full code looks like:

```
def json_list(list):
  lst = []
  for pn in list:
    lst.append(pn)
  return json.dumps(lst)

fh = open(wholefName)
fc = fh.read()
fh.close()
markerArray = fc.splitlines()

print json_list( markerArray )
```

I am running *Jython* with Python 2.6.2**** on Windows.

****Edit: I apologize, we are running Python 2.5.2 on Windows.

Comment: I'm still stuck on reading 900 lines taking 11 seconds. How long are these lines?! In CPython, reading and splitting a 900 line file with `x=json.dumps([l.strip() for l in open('testfile.txt')])` took 2 mS on my laptop. What with disk latencies and all, I could see it taking as long as 40 mS, but not 11 seconds.

Comment: Each line is between 15 and 20 characters, a-zA-Z0-9

Comment: That's a small file (<20K) and simply reading it should be very fast. You've got something else going on. Is it on a network drive that is seriously ill? Is your hard drive failing?

Comment: It's local and the harddrive is fairly new. I'm running a few more tests... it is very possible my timer was stopping after additional code was being ran or not finishing entirely.

Comment: yeah, those numbers are way off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the function call (which is useless), it should be faster.

```
with open(wholefName) as fh:
    json.dumps(fh.read().splitlines())
```

Another thing to be aware of is that, in Python 2, there are two versions of the `json` module: one written in pure Python, the other in C. As Jython, as I know of, doesn't support C extensions, it is likely that you're using the Python version, which is necessarily slower. Your best would be to write your code in Java.

Comment: Well, it isn't the JSON library causing problems, it is .splitlines() and .strip(). Iterating over the list and doing work on it is what takes so long (From what I can tell).

Edit: Our JSON module is simplejson

Comment: Second comment (And apologies), we are running Python 2.5.2 where "with" is not a keyword. I have updated my original question.

Comment: There are chances that your Jython version is somewhat bugged. For me, on CPython, opening a file which contains 130000 lines, reading its content, and splitting the lines takes 0.2 seconds.

Comment: So after another few hours of testing, we did narrow it down to simplejson's implementation of .load()

138 seconds of all 142 seconds is spent doing this work, so we're re-evaluating our options at this point.

I'll mark this as the answer since you had it dead it to rights. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to convert the text file to a json-encoded string is:

```
def file_to_json(filename):
    return json.dumps([l.strip() for l in open(filename)])
```

If you really wanted to just save the result to a new file, you can skip the intermediate stuff:

```
def file_to_json(from_filename, to_filename):
    json.dump([l.strip() for l in open(from_filename)],
        open(to_filename, 'w'))
```

Comment: We also ended up using your first suggestion, even though our main problem happened to be with simplejson. Here, have an upvote!